# How change flexdashbord::gauge's label in shiny application with reactive data?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I would like the gauge label to change when the value changes.

I created the `f_3` function to try to adjust this, but not succeed.

My `rmarkdown` code:

````
---
title: "Label of gauge"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: yeti
---

side{.sidebar}
-------------------------------------------

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(flexdashboard)
```

**Analysis**

```{r}
autonumericInput(
    inputId = "a", 
    value = 10, 
    label = "Value 1", 
    align = "center", 
    currencySymbol = "$", 
    currencySymbolPlacement = "p",
    digitGroupSeparator = ".",
    decimalCharacter = ",", 
    decimalPlaces = 0, 
    minimumValue = 0, 
    maximumValue = 100
)

autonumericInput(
    inputId = "b", 
    value = 10, 
    label = "Value 2", 
    align = "center", 
    currencySymbol = "R$", 
    currencySymbolPlacement = "p", 
    digitGroupSeparator = ".",
    decimalCharacter = ",", 
    decimalPlaces = 0, 
    minimumValue = 0, 
    maximumValue = 100
    )
```

```{r}
f_1 <- function(a, b) {
  a + b
}

reac <- reactive({
  tibble(
    a = input$a, 
    b = input$b
  )
})

pred <- reactive({
  temp <- reac()
  f_1(
    a = input$a, 
    b = input$b
  )
})
```

abc{}
--------------------------------------

###
```{r}
f_3 <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 40) {
    "Danger"
  } else if (x <= 80) {
    "Warning"
  } else ("Success")
}

renderGauge({
  gauge(
    value = round(x = pred(), digits = 0), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%", 
    label = f_3(x = pred())
    )
})
```
````

[image]

The label's value always appears as `Danger`, even when the value changes. What can you do for it to change as the value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like a bug to me. You can open an issue in the {flexdashboard} github and tell them to fix it.

Meanwhile, I have a workaround for you. This requires you to have some advanced understanding of Shiny, I guess that is beyond what you have learned so far, so I am not gonna explain the details. Read this [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) if you are interested. In simple words, we write our own Shiny methods to communicate with the web UI and update the UI.

````
---
title: "Label of gauge"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: yeti
---

side{.sidebar}
-------------------------------------------

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(flexdashboard)
```

**Analysis**

```{r}
autonumericInput(
    inputId = "a", 
    value = 10, 
    label = "Value 1", 
    align = "center", 
    currencySymbol = "$", 
    currencySymbolPlacement = "p",
    digitGroupSeparator = ".",
    decimalCharacter = ",", 
    decimalPlaces = 0, 
    minimumValue = 0, 
    maximumValue = 100
)

autonumericInput(
    inputId = "b", 
    value = 10, 
    label = "Value 2", 
    align = "center", 
    currencySymbol = "R$", 
    currencySymbolPlacement = "p", 
    digitGroupSeparator = ".",
    decimalCharacter = ",", 
    decimalPlaces = 0, 
    minimumValue = 0, 
    maximumValue = 100
    )
```

```{r}
f_1 <- function(a, b) {
  a + b
}

reac <- reactive({
  tibble(
    a = input$a, 
    b = input$b
  )
})

pred <- reactive({
  temp <- reac()
  f_1(
    a = input$a, 
    b = input$b
  )
})
```

abc{}
--------------------------------------

###
<div id="gauge">

```{r}
f_3 <- function(x) {
  if (x <= 40) {
    "Danger"
  } else if (x <= 80) {
    "Warning"
  } else "Success"
}

renderGauge({
    session$sendCustomMessage("gauge-text",list(text = f_3(x = pred())))
  gauge(
    value = round(x = pred(), digits = 0), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = "%",
    label = "Danger"
    )
})
```

<script>
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('gauge-text', data=>{
    document.querySelector('#section-gauge svg text[font-size="10px"] tspan').innerHTML = data.text 
})
</script>
</div>
````